# Convert text file into pdf

Tags: python, pdf

I have a task to convert simple text file into pdf format. Also I need to add a header to that newly created pdf file.
The server which will have this text file and will convert it does not have any Microsoft Office document or other tools for conversion. One suggested to use python for that task since the server has it installed.
Could you please help me to start with conversion from text to pdf using python?
P.S. My system does not have pyPdf module and I failed to install it.

Thanks
Here is some update:
I run some program which at the end generate manifest. Manifest is a simple text file which looks like .csv file but columns are separated by white space. I ship this manifest to client. My current task is to ship to client additionally to this manifest another file which should have the same content and the header with the client name and be in PDF format.

Comment: You'll need to use an external library to do this in Python, so if you failed to install the PyPDF module, you should provide us with some details to make us able to help you. (please update your *question*, not add extra information in the comments)

Comment: a quick google search came up with several other libraries that appear to be able to do this, have you looked at any of those?

Comment: - Dannno. My problem is that that program runs on a server with a limited access and I won't be able to install any additional software. That's why I think about python which is already there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am all set now.
I figured out that my server already has pdf installed and the only thing I had to do was to call it. Sorry for confusion.
Ticket could be closed.

Comment: Please close the ticket.